# Is there a way to easily integrate service worker into angular 2?

Tags: angular, webpack, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I recently having a hard time to integrate service worker into my project, i was planning to build PWA. I already searching over the internet, but no luck. Using --mobile flag for creating project is not supported anymore. I tried to use webpack plugin for service worker but it's too much complicated for me. i mean like configuring the page route & content caching for the service worker to work. i hope if there's tutorial for this.

Comment: Check this [Github](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/wiki) if it can help you. It has a feature regarding Basic Service Worker, which implements "Cache then network strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add gulp task or use with command line cli to build progressive web app 
try with -> https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.